# Fullcalendar background-image for fc-sun

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullcalendar

I set background-image for sunday in month view, but also the day "Sunday" in header is set with same background, while others header days is set correctly. I see that css for table thread have .fc-sun .fc-mon etc. too, but I don't kwow how remove these class from thread. How can I solve this problem ?

I have this in my fullcalendar.css :

```
.fc-widget-header{
background-color: #900;
}

.fc-sun {
  background-image:url('../img/myImage.png');
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
  background-repeat:repeat-y;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an element selector to your css, since the day "Sunday" header (th) and day body(td) has fc-sun class. This solution should fit your case.

```
td.fc-sun {
  background-image:url('../img/myImage.png');
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
  background-repeat:repeat-y;
}
```